# How to translate 7:00 pm "sharp"?

Tags: adverbes, indications-de-temps

In French, how does one translate the word "sharp" in a phrase like "we'll begin at 7:00 pm sharp". [An online dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/sharp) gives "pile", as in "à sept heures pile", but this doesn't sound right to me. Is "pile" a legit translation?

Also, if it's different, how would the phrase be said in Canadian French?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"*Pile*" is indeed legit in this context. As an adverb, *pile* means "precise" or "exact". So "*à sept heures pile*" or "*à dix-neuf heures pile*" means "at exactly 7 o'clock".

Alternatively, one can use "*sonnant*" as an adjective to convey the same meaning. Coming from the verb "*sonner*", it refers to clocks chiming at the hour. Therefore you can also say "*à sept heures sonnantes*" or "*à dix-neuf heures sonnantes*".

Those two would be understood in Canadian French, but "*pile*" is more widely used.

Comment: In France, *X heures tapantes* is more common than *X heures sonnantes*. I just learned that [this is a recent phenomenon](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heures+sonnantes%2Cheures+tapantes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: You could also think of *"pétantes"*, even though it is more colloquial but still used a lot when speaking nowadays.

Comment: I would also suggest “*sept heures précises*”, with a slight doubt with how to make “*précises*“ agree.

Answer (score 4):

The usual translation in French is indeed “*à sept heures pile*”, at least in France. [Kareen confirms](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7682) that this is also common in Québec.

A traditional way to express this would be “*à sept heures sonnantes*”, meaning “as the (Church) bell is ringing the seventh hour”. In the early 20th century, other synonymous expressions appeared in writing: “*à sept heures tapantes*” (which is more common than *sonnantes* nowadays), “*à sept heures pétantes*” (colloquial, not normally used in writing).

In “*à sept heures pile*”, *pile* is used as an adverb. This relates to the meaning of *pile* as the tail side of a coin. In the early to mid-20th century, the word *pile* came to mean brusquely, sharply; as far as I can tell, this evokes a coin that lands sharply (and noisily) on a table and stops moving. For example “*s'arrêter pile*” means to stop abrubtly (and this gave rise to the verb *piler* with this meaning). Around the same time, and presumably arising from this meaning, *pile* started to be used with time, to mean an exact time : “*être pile à l'heure*” (to be exactly on time), “*sept heures pile*” (seven o'clock sharp).

The use of *pile* as an adverb is mostly colloquial, but after a time it is well received in writing.